# Get the array from nested query and foreach loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js, foreach

I am doing nested query and its results are looped to get the desired data from it 
Code:

```
db.query("select * from user where CheckIn IS NULL order by checkIn", function (err, isCheck) {
  if (!_.size(isCheck))
  return db.end()
    var queries = []

    isCheck.forEach(function (item, i, data) {
      var CheckIn = data[i].CheckIn
      var id = data[i].id
      db.query("select * from user where checkIn > ? and date(checkIn) = date(?) order by checkIn limit 1", [checkIn, checkIn], function (err, updateCheck) {
      if(!_.size(updateCheck))
      return
        updateCheckOut.forEach(function (item, j, data2) {
          var difftm = moment(data2[j].checkIn).diff(moment(checkIn), 'minutes')
           if(difftm == 0)
            var updatedNewCheckOut = data2[j].checkIn
           if(difftm >= 1)
            var updatedNewCheckOut = 'SUBDATE('+ data2[j].checkIn +', INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)'
           if(difftm > 600)
            var updatedNewCheckOut = 'DATE_ADD('+ data2[j].checkIn + ', INTERVAL 10 HOUR)'

            queries.push([updatedNewCheckOut, 1, id])
        })
      })
    })
    console.log(queries) // null array 
})
```

i want queries to display the data in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your isCheck.forEach function. You need to handle it asynchronously. You can use [each from async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)  library.

```js
db.query("select * from user where CheckIn IS NULL order by checkIn", function (err, data) {
    if (!_.size(data)){
        return db.end()
    }
    var queries = []
    async.each(data, function (item, done) {
        var CheckIn = item.CheckIn
        var id = item.id
        db.query("select * from user where checkIn > ? and date(checkIn) = date(?) order by checkIn limit 1", [checkIn, checkIn], function (err, updateCheck) {
            if (!_.size(updateCheck)) return done()
            updateCheckOut.forEach(function (item, j, data2) {
                var difftm = moment(data2[j].checkIn).diff(moment(checkIn), 'minutes')
                if (difftm == 0)
                    var updatedNewCheckOut = data2[j].checkIn
                if (difftm >= 1)
                    var updatedNewCheckOut = 'SUBDATE(' + data2[j].checkIn + ', INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)'
                if (difftm > 600)
                    var updatedNewCheckOut = 'DATE_ADD(' + data2[j].checkIn + ', INTERVAL 10 HOUR)'

                queries.push([updatedNewCheckOut, 1, id])
               
            });
            done()
        })
    }, function(er){
        console.log("everything `enter code here`has completed")
        console.log("Err: ", er)
        console.log("Queries: ", queries)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the console.log immediately after the updateCheckOut.forEach loop.

Comment: there i will get the array,but i need that array outside the forEach loop

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you use `let` instead of `var` as it will save you from your loop variables being available outside the loop.

Because you are running an asynchronous function (db.query) in a loop, your `console.log(queries)` actually ends up running before any of the db.queries finish and push to the queries array.

You want to run all the db queries in parallel. [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) makes that possible, as do several promise libraries. You want to write the command so that after all queries is finished, `console.log`.

Comment: here in my code how to use promise ?, data is coming from the query

Comment: Please can you show how to use promise.all in here. Examples in the link is not clear to me